# Avoiding accidental update when trying to insert placeholder values into CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

I've got a simple app, where I'm trying to allow a user to add Rides to a Week (class schedule). There is a One to Many relationship from weeks to rides.

When a user adds a new ride - I want to insert a placeholder/dummy ride - which I'll later update.

The issue I'm having is that the 'placeholderRide' dummy item that I've created below works fine in the first instance - but from that point forward, it is actually adding a new ride to the database, and mapping that new ride to the correct week - but it is UNSETTING the reference from the previously added Ride - so the end result is a max of one Ride per week being inserted (though the DB is ending up with lots of orphan rides!). Even after app restart.

Clearly the issue has to do with this placeholderRide not being a 'new' item created each time I call the function, but instead it is just updating it.

I'm sure I'm missing the obvious - but what should I change to insert a blank new ride each time? And if I want to insert 10 new rides, I actually insert them instead of inserting a new row, but overriding the existing relationships, such that only one row has a relationship to the week?

```
@IBAction func addRideButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let placeholderRide = TempRide(context: context) //create a new ride to insert
    placeholderRide.week = tempWeeks?[0] //set the reference for that ride to the first week
    placeholderRide.rideTitle = "New Ride"  // set the title

    rideFilterForSelectedWeek(for: tempWeeks![0]) //set the tempRides array to hold only the
    // rides for the first week in the array (as we always insert the new item into the first week)

    tempRides?.append(placeholderRide) //it is this one that is UPDATING the existing placeholder ride rather than appending on a new one

    self.saveRides()
    }
```

How I get the rides from CoreData:

```
func rideFilterForSelectedWeek(for selectedWeek: TempWeek) {
        let request : NSFetchRequest<TempRide> = TempRide.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "week == %@", selectedWeek)
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "rideSequenceInWeek", ascending: true)]
        loadRides(with: request)
    }
```

And loading rides:

```
func loadRides(with request: NSFetchRequest<TempRide> = TempRide.fetchRequest()) {
    do{
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "rideSequenceInWeek", ascending: true)]
        tempRides = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
    }
}
```

And the saveRides function:

```
func saveRides() {
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Error saving context \(error)")
    }
    loadRides()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...after working on this one for ages and finally posting a question, it was the basics - I had a 'To One' relationship set instead of 'To Many'.  Changed that and problems solved!